# Python: Comparing two Directories for Different Filenames

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have to compare two directories with .xyz files in them. One directory has original files (names xa02-1-1-1-1, xa02-1-1-1-2 etc.). I process all these files (molecules) and each file gives rise to 3 new files whose file names just have -1, -2, -3 added at the end. (e.g., *xa02-1-1-1-1* would give rise to *xa02-1-1-1-1-1*, *xa02-1-1-1-1-2*, and *xa02-1-1-1-1-3*). During this operation some files just produce two new files and don't produce the 3rd or some produce just one new file and some even do not produce any output. I want to compare first folder with the new one seeing which files have not generated 3 new files. Basically I want t list of the files in the first folder which did not give rise to 3 new files.
I did not find how to do it with Python so I printed all the filenames using bash without the extensions. Now I have two text files with all the filenames and I compare those two text files. I am trying to remove the last -1, -2, -3 from the new list and see if an item in original file is present in the new list less than 3 times. The code still gives me count 1 for all the files.
Can anyone please guide me on that how to do it efficiently using Python. I need this for my PhD research as doing this manually takes days just to compare two folders because of lots of files (molecules) in them.
Here is the code I wrote:

```
# Define the lists which contain the filenames to compare
originals = "orig-files.txt"
next_step_filenames = "new-files.txt"

def read_input_file(input_filename):
    f = open(input_filename, 'r')
    fr = f.readlines()
    f.close()
    return fr
# Read the files with filenames and without extensions
original_files = read_input_file(originals)  
next_step_files = read_input_file(next_step_filenames) 

original_files_trimmed = []  # Removing the last \n from every line
for a in original_files:
    original_files_trimmed.append(a[:-1])

next_step_files_trimmed = []  # A list with the last -1, -2, -3 removed
for i in next_step_files:
    next_step_files_trimmed.append(i[:-3])

Final_list = [] # List for Files who generate <3 files 
for m in original_files_trimmed:
    for n in next_step_files_trimmed:
        count = 0
        if m in n:
            count =+ 1
            if count < 3:
                Final_list.append(m)

for b in Final_list:
    print(b)
```

And here are the files with names in them.
**orig-files.txt**

```
xa02-1-1-1-1
xa02-1-1-1-2
xa02-1-1-2-3
xa02-1-3-3-3
xa06-3-1-2-1
xa07-1-2-1-1
```

**new-files.txt**

```
xa02-1-1-1-1-1
xa02-1-1-1-1-2
xa02-1-1-1-1-3
xa02-1-1-1-2-1
xa02-1-1-1-2-2
xa02-1-1-1-2-3
xa02-1-1-2-3-1
xa02-1-3-3-3-1
xa02-1-3-3-3-2
xa06-3-1-2-1-1
xa06-3-1-2-1-2
xa06-3-1-2-1-3
```

You can see in the files that *xa02-1-1-2-3* and *xa02-1-3-3-3* generate 1 and 2 files, respectively while *xa07-1-2-1-1* did not generate any output file. I want the output to look like this:

```
xa02-1-1-2-3   1
xa02-1-3-3-3   2
xa07-1-2-1-1   0
```

Please help me here. I would be highly thankful for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `Counter` to count occurrence of filename having trimmed away the last 2 characters.
The resulting counter object can be used to filter `original_files_trimmed` where items don't count up to 3.

#### Example:

```
from collections import Counter

original_files_trimmed = [
  'xa02-1-1-1-1',
  'xa02-1-1-1-2',
  'xa02-1-1-2-3',
  'xa02-1-3-3-3',
  'xa06-3-1-2-1',
  'xa07-1-2-1-1',
]
next_step_files_trimmed = [
  'xa02-1-1-1-1-1',
  'xa02-1-1-1-1-2',
  'xa02-1-1-1-1-3',
  'xa02-1-1-1-2-1',
  'xa02-1-1-1-2-2',
  'xa02-1-1-1-2-3',
  'xa02-1-1-2-3-1',
  'xa02-1-3-3-3-1',
  'xa02-1-3-3-3-2',
  'xa06-3-1-2-1-1',
  'xa06-3-1-2-1-2',
  'xa06-3-1-2-1-3'
]

# These next few lines diff original_files_trimmed and 
# next_step_files_trimmed using the defined rules
next_step_files_without_num = (n[:-2] for n in next_step_files_trimmed) ## trim last 2 chars    
next_step_files_without_num_cnt = Counter(next_step_files_without_num)
final_list = [
   m for m in original_files_trimmed 
   if next_step_files_without_num_cnt[m] < 3
]

print(final_list)
```

Comment: And to get the file names without hard coding them or putting them in a file first, you can use [`os.listdir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir) or [`glob.glob()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob).

Comment: Yeah, `os.listdir` is a better way to go if looking one-level in the directory.

Comment: Thank you so much @Oluwafemi Sule and @Blurp. Real quick help. Appreciate it. I'll use `os.listdir()` which is way more convenient than the method I used.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one implementation:

```
def updateHash(d, key):
    if key not in d.keys():
        d[key] = 3
    else:
        d[key] -= 1

originals = "orig-files.txt"
next_step_filenames = "new-files.txt"

originals_list = []
with open(originals, 'r') as f:
    originals_list = f.read().splitlines()

next_step_list = []
with open(next_step_filenames, 'r') as f:
    next_step_list = f.read().splitlines()

expected_list = []
d = {}
for orig in originals_list:
    if orig + '-1' not in next_step_list:
        updateHash(d, orig)
    if orig + '-2' not in next_step_list:
        updateHash(d, orig)
    if orig + '-3' not in next_step_list:
        updateHash(d, orig)

print d
```

Comment: Thanks @Nish for your kind help. Can I please ask you to explain little this `updateHash` function as I could not completely get it. And also can I print it in column form at the end rather than printing in one row?